# Discussion Forum Email Templates HTML

Tags: wygwam, forum, discussion

I have changed Default Mail Format to HTML in email configuration but when I get email notifcations via the Discussion Forum it still contains HTML tags .

e.g., `<p>`

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The "default email format" setting does only one thing, and that is determine the initial state of the "Email Format" dropdown when you go to **Tools → Communicate**.

All other emails generated by EE - be it from the Forum module, or comment notifications, new entry notifications, etc - will be sent as plain text. Currently there is no way to change that without altering core files.